# How are apps installed on Android ? context - symbolic links of only some apps disappear after reboot

Tags: security, installation, mount, app2sd, selinux

I am using `Apps2sd` to move some apps to `ext4 partition mmcblk1p2`. It successfully moved 1 app ( see code below ) but after linking  another , the `symblink` for app gets deleted but data folder's `symblink` preserved so after boot the apk ( 'disappears' ) . Everything is the same in terms of ownership and security context ( `SeLinux` ). 
 I cant dig up anything  of interest from `dmesg`. *Why does this happen ?*  Both apps are User Apps . Both apps have everything possible `linked`. One App remains 'alive' & the other 'disappears' after `boot` . `SeLinux is Permissive` . `This is an Android Q Project Treble ROM`
 I am not using `App2sd`native mount script, ( though my ROM has `addon.sh` support and I tossed `App2sd`native mount script in there ) but, `Partition mmcblk1p2` which is `sdext2` is `mounted`  through my own script . 1 line of thinking ruled out was `Partition mmcblk1p2` which is `sdext2` is being `mounted`  late enough & before that itself the `symlink` is considered invalid & gets deleted but that wont explain why the other app survives ? 
*In the below 'camscanner' is the app that persists after boot and 'BofA' which is bank Of America disappears.*

### `Apk` directories

```
PrKr:/data/sdext2/apk # ls -al /data/app/com.intsig.camscanner-WRx5fzxsezoqL6Gc53H5qg==
total 21760
drwxrwxr-x   3 system system      4096 2020-04-02 10:42 .
drwxrwx--x 114 system system     20480 2020-04-15 08:24 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root          72 2020-03-29 17:43 base.apk -> /data/sdext2/apk/com.intsig.camscanner-WRx5fzxsezoqL6Gc53H5qg==/base.apk
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root          71 2020-03-29 17:43 lib -> /data/sdext2/app-lib/com.intsig.camscanner-WRx5fzxsezoqL6Gc53H5qg==/lib
drwxrwx--x   3 system install     4096 2020-03-29 17:43 oat
-rw-r--r--   1 system system  22239154 2020-03-29 17:43 split_config.armeabi.apk

PrKr:/data/sdext2/apk # ls -alZ $_
total 21760
drwxrwxr-x   3 system system  u:object_r:apk_data_file:s0             4096 2020-04-02 10:42 .
drwxrwx--x 114 system system  u:object_r:apk_data_file:s0            20480 2020-04-15 08:24 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root    u:object_r:mnt_user_file:s0               72 2020-03-29 17:43 base.apk -> /data/sdext2/apk/com.intsig.camscanner-WRx5fzxsezoqL6Gc53H5qg==/ba
se.apk
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root    u:object_r:mnt_user_file:s0               71 2020-03-29 17:43 lib -> /data/sdext2/app-lib/com.intsig.camscanner-WRx5fzxsezoqL6Gc53H5qg==/lib

drwxrwx--x   3 system install u:object_r:dalvikcache_data_file:s0     4096 2020-03-29 17:43 oat
-rw-r--r--   1 system system  u:object_r:apk_data_file:s0         22239154 2020-03-29 17:43 split_config.armeabi.apk
```

and BofAm. This is *before* reboot. the below link gets deleted after reboot. I am posting the pre-boot scenario for comparison. Nothing to post , after reboot as the link is deleted

```
130|PrKr:/data/sdext2/apk # ls -al /data/app/com.infonow.bofa-N_WOiCdzw7ZF21E7EtehGQ==
total 40
drwxrwxr-x   3 system system   4096 2020-04-15 08:26 .
drwxrwx--x 114 system system  20480 2020-04-15 08:24 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root       67 2020-04-15 08:24 base.apk -> /data/sdext2/apk/com.infonow.bofa-N_WOiCdzw7ZF21E7EtehGQ==/base.apk
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root       66 2020-04-15 08:24 lib -> /data/sdext2/app-lib/com.infonow.bofa-N_WOiCdzw7ZF21E7EtehGQ==/lib
drwxrwx--x   3 system install  4096 2020-04-15 08:24 oat

PrKr:/data/sdext2/apk # ls -alZ $_
total 40
drwxrwxr-x   3 system system  u:object_r:apk_data_file:s0          4096 2020-04-15 08:26 .
drwxrwx--x 114 system system  u:object_r:apk_data_file:s0         20480 2020-04-15 08:24 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root    u:object_r:mnt_user_file:s0            67 2020-04-15 08:24 base.apk -> /data/sdext2/apk/com.infonow.bofa-N_WOiCdzw7ZF21E7EtehGQ==/base.apk
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root    u:object_r:mnt_user_file:s0            66 2020-04-15 08:24 lib -> /data/sdext2/app-lib/com.infonow.bofa-N_WOiCdzw7ZF21E7EtehGQ==/lib
drwxrwx--x   3 system install u:object_r:dalvikcache_data_file:s0  4096 2020-04-15 08:24 oat
```

### Questions

How can  I get this to work ? 
Also `SeLinux` being `permissive avc denials` are just FYI or they are in force ? `restorcon` and other `selinux` commands are regardless or matter ?

What I did so far :
--tinkered with various options including putting `magisk` in `global mount space` 

-- ran a `umask` command before link re-creation after deleting the original `link` as mentioned [here](http://omasse.blogspot.com/2009/12/performing-chmod-on-symbolic-link.html) to make that link RO . `Link octals` remain the same viz 777 
-- `restorecon` though i dunno why that'd matter if I am running in permissive mode ?

I manage to get some more information from log cat and here it is on  [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/V5PxFdcX)
**Update :**

Heyya thanks. I put mount scripts in  [`pastebin_2_with_MountScipts`](https://pastebin.com/8hsrSbqZ) with relevant notes on top ``  and the earlier [`pastebin_1_with_logCat`](https://pastebin.com/V5PxFdcX) has some more info from `logcat` it sounds like something deleted `/data/app/com.infonow.bofa-jnpc8sttz4BVPzQsPK5zw==/base.apk`  the `symblink`. What process was it ? after that I can see `package manager` is complaining  and doing clean ups . One thing still unclear. Does `SeLinux Context` matter in `permissive` mode ?. TYVM

Comment: i think you have answered question yourself already. sdext2 is mounted too late, that's a common reason for such behavior (some apps dissapear, some not)

Comment: Howdy that seemingly convinces had it not been 1) Another App getting mounted just fine. Everything is the same as I mentioned how come the other one mounts fine  ? 2 ) if I link everything except the `apk ` . The other components `/data/app/<name>/lib --> /data/sdext2/app-lib/ mounts` just fine, which tells me something else is going on. What possibly can explain this differential behavior ?

Comment: also if `SeLinux ` is `permissive avc denials `  ( from `dmesg` ) are just FYI or they are in force ?

Comment: Updated the question with this info

Comment: ...in  `permissive` mode does  `context` matter. From  that lil drop I know of the 'sea' called `selinux`. If   `permissive` those  `avc` denials are just FYI or `context`matters  ? Yes the app does move  when it links and  the owner & everything  is ditto  for the app that  survives a reboot Vs that whose link is lost.. I will do some more use case testing and revert back and I will also give your  loop a try. Thanks AlecXS

Comment: i don't know but i guess avc denials always matters, otherwise it would not named denials. but that is no explanation because you did same with other symlinks. maybe the app itself checks for symlink because it's s banking app

Answer (score 1):

This is example mount script `/data/adb/service.d/40sdext2`

```
#!/system/bin/sh
[ -d /data/sdext2 ] && \
until grep -qw /data/sdext2 /proc/mounts
  do
    mount -t ext4 -o rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /data/sdext2
done &
```

Comment: can be placed in `/data/adb/post-fs-data.d` or `/data/adb/service.d` should work in both cases

Comment: downvote if not solves your symlink problem

Comment: nah... never ever downvote someone's best efforts after all....  w/out efforts there will not be results. tend  to avoid using loops in in `Su` level scripts since they can cause boot loops. I have no complain about my script not being able to mount. does mount but I am not sure if the problem is the  `mount` timing or there is another issue

Comment: I am less inclined to think about the Mount timing because the same app will link without any issues if I link the `data lib  odex`  everything except `apk ` ... the minute I link just apk  it will refuse   to show up after a reboot

Comment: Ok I got it to work w/ the following modifications.  I was running my `mount script` from `/data/adb/modules/<name>/script.sh` which actually came from my old phone that I did not bother to change. I took your cue and tossed it in /`data/adb/service.d ` giving it the right `chmod`'s it needed  after that I suspected the `davik cache` must be telling the older location before the move, though, if there's a `symblink` in there then  it should feel nothing changed..so cleared `dalvik cache` & the apps would reappear with links in place. So Alec - `TYVM`

Comment: bad thing that  happened after `dalvik cache` was cleared.. it deleted the `msgstore.db` file in `/data/sdext2/data/com.whatsapp`  & similar files. I dunno why cant follow but I had a 12 hr ago backup.Likely because that file was cached being write prone ..still wonder how just that 1gb+ file was `del` & other files present ? Though `apps2sd` for some might be antique ( it hasnt updated recently).-. When it works as it shd I dont need `titanium`.Prev2Prev phone shorted & bricked  in my jacket -snow from my jacket but bcos of `linked app & data` I minimized data loss.